# Is there a way to keep video files within my app that will be installed on the sd card?

Tags: android, file, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am new to Android developing. I have lots of videos around the size of 500MB. I have been testing my app but i always transfered the videos through the usb cable and not directly through my app. Is there a way to embed these videos within my app so that they are automatically transfered to the sdcard? I just need to know if it is possible or not.

Comment: do you need to pack all your videos within the final APK file of your application ?

Comment: don't you think 500MB video file is big, for an Android mobile application ?

Comment: Its big for phone but i am relying on tablet.

Comment: even then the market don't allow you to do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think it is possible at all to store all your videos inside your app and make the final APK out of that.

beacuse, Android market has a size limitation of **50MB**. see here http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/12/android-market-client-update.html

Answer (score 0):

pratcise is, that developer (especially in the games section), let the users download a small basic application which downloads the rest over the network (if WiFi is available), so that the user doesn't have to download a sh*tload of stuff if he wants to install your app, let say while he is outside, using GPRS/UTMS, or roaming...

Comment: I said i am testing the app. When I upload it to Google play store, I will obviously use the APK Expansion Files.[http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html]

Comment: no, you said that you have been testing the app... anyway, I see your question was answered already ;)